# Why is DMux4way operate like this?

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

When the sel is 01 the b should be chosen, but why the operation is a = nsel1 b = sel[0]? After that the sel will become 00 from 01

```
CHIP DMux4Way {
IN in, sel[2];
OUT a, b, c, d;

PARTS:
// Put your code here:
Not(in = sel[0], out = nsel0);
Not(in = sel[1], out = nsel1);
And(a = nsel1, b = nsel0, out = s00);
And(a = in, b = s00, out = a);
And(a = nsel1, b = sel[0], out = s01);
And(a = in, b = s01, out = b);
And(a = sel[1], b = nsel0, out = s10);
And(a = in, b = s10, out = c);
And(a = sel[1], b = sel[0], out = s11);
And(a = in, b = s11, out = d);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In each pair of ANDs, the first one determines whether the output is activated, and the second one gates the input to that output.

So:

And(a = nsel1, b = nsel0, out = s00);

s00 is True only if both its inputs (nsel0 and nsel1) are True. Since they are the inverse of sel[0] and sel[1], s00 will only be true if both sel[0] and sel[1] are False.

And(a = in, b = s00, out = a);

The second And will only be true if both in and s00 are True. So it will only be True if in is True, and sel[0] and sel[1] are False.

Similar logic applies for the other cases. But the key point is that for the 01 and 10 cases, it is not enough to check that the right value is True, you also have to check that the other value is 0.

Edit: In addition, as the OP points out in a subsequent comment, the machine is little-endian, and you must keep this in mind when operating on a multi-bit bus (like sel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what makes me confused is that "And(a = nsel1, b = sel[0], out = s01)" will change the sel from 01 to 00 when it should be output from b. Then the "And(a = in, b = s01, out = b);" will always be 0.

Comment: One thing that may be confusing you is that in the "And(a = nsel1, b = sel[0], out = s01)", a and b are input parameters to the And. They don't affect the a and b outputs of the chip as a whole. Those are only set in the second And, when they are connected to the out parameter of that component.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out because the hack uses little endian.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).